# All inactive with circle selection

Tags: selection-tools, select

[image]
I tried to use free camera with Shift+F but I it didn't work. After that circle appeared around my cursor (and I can scale it with mouse wheel) and I could change objects. But all tabs became inactive (I cant even choose file to save my project) and I can't do anything except closing blender. I can easily remake project but for the future please help is it a bug or feature?I tried deselecting all with A+A and deselecting Circle Selection with C but it didn't do anything
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press esc to get out of selection mode.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Also can you how to get rid of this circle around cursor?

Comment: I solved it: I accidently pressed W and chose another type of seletion.